# iPad: Tables in Popover Views do not Scroll to Show Selected Row

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am having two problems with viewcontrollerss in landscape orientation on the iPad.

(1) I have two popups which hold tables. The tables should scroll to a specific row to reflect a selection in the main view. Instead, the tables do scroll down some but the actual selected row remains off screen.

(2) All my action sheets come up with a width of 320.

In Interface Builder, all my views are created in landscape orientation.  Only the main Window is not, but I don't see a way to change that.

**My Configuration:** Upon launch, I get the following coordinates for my main window and the main viewcontroller view:

```
Window frame {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}} mainView frame {{0, 0}, {748, 1024}}
```

All other views after that show these coordinates when summoned (when loaded but before being presented):

```
    frame of keysig {{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}
    frame of instrumentSelect {{20, 0}, {1024, 768}}
    frame of settings {{0, 0}, {467, 300}}
```

In all my viewControllers, i respond to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` with:

```
            return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
                        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
```

Everything (almost) functions as expected.  The app launches into one of the two landscape modes.  The views (and viewcontrollers) display everything where it belongs and taps work all across the screen as expected.  However, I still have the two problems.

**Problem 1:** I have two popups containing tables long enough to run off screen. The tables should scroll to a selected row. They do scroll i.e. they don't start visually at row 1 but they don't scroll enough to actually show the selected row.

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/mahboud//Public/keysig.png](http://idisk.mac.com/mahboud//Public/keysig.png)

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/mahboud//Public/instrumentlist.png](http://idisk.mac.com/mahboud//Public/instrumentlist.png)

It almost seems like a UITable internal rect gets created with the wrong number and stays that way but I've checked both of the UITableView's scrollView content coordinates and they seemed reasonable.

**Problem 2:** I think this is related to problem 1 because my actionsheets come up with a width of 320.  I can only assume that the iPad allows actionSheets in only 320 or 480 widths and since it somehow thinks that the screen is oriented in portrait mode, it uses the narrower width.

There you have it.  I can't believe I am still getting hung up on orientation issues.  I swear Apple doesn't make it easy to have a landscape app.  Any ideas?

Comment: This was a good question. You obviously took some time with it. However, you buried the actual questions way down in the body. People had to read several hundred words just fine out what your problem was. In the future, put the problem at the top followed by any detail. More people will read and respond to your question if they don't have to struggle to figure out what problem you're asking about. I've edited the question to a more easy to read format.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured it out.  If I take the

```
[self.tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

out of either the -viewDidAppear or -viewWillAppear, and instead put it right after my -presentPopoverFrom..., then it works:

```
[popController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:keySigBBItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

[keySignatureTableVC.tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```

What must be happening is that both -viewDidAppear and -viewWillAppear must be getting called before presentPopover... resizes or reorients the view.  What I do in those two methods isn't working on the correct frame or bounds.  Scrolling after seems to work.